# Cannot launch fragment: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having the "child already has a parent" error close to what a lot of people have been getting, however, I am getting it doing something different (as far as my searches have shown me). I am assuming that the way I am adding the fragment is not necessarily wrong, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how the fragment I am adding already has a parent.

I am launching from my main activity using a fragment to be loaded into a FrameLayout. Here is the onCreate from my main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

    }

    tripsFragment = new CarTripsOverview();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_container, tripsFragment).commit();
}
```

And here are the methods which run for CarTripsOverview (which is a Fragment):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {

    }

    setUpRealm();
}

void setUpRealm() {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmQuery<Car> carQuery = realm.where(Car.class);
    RealmResults<Car> carResults = carQuery.findAll();
    carAdapter = new CarArrayAdapter(getActivity(),0, carResults, true);

    RealmQuery<Trip> tripQuery = realm.where(Trip.class);
    RealmResults<Trip> tripResults = tripQuery.findAll();
    tripAdapter = new TripAdapterRealm(getActivity(), 0, tripResults, true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_trips_overview, container, true);

    // Bind all of the views with Butter Knife
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    setUpSwipeMenu();

    // Add my event listeners
    tripListView.setAdapter(tripAdapter);

    carSpinner.setAdapter(carAdapter);

    return view;
}

void setUpSwipeMenu() {
    SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {
        @Override
        public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
            SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(getContext());
            deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
            deleteItem.setWidth(MathHelper.dipToPixels(getContext(), 90));
            deleteItem.setTitle("Delete");
            deleteItem.setTitleColor(Color.WHITE);
            deleteItem.setTitleSize(18);
            menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
        }
    };

    tripListView.setMenuCreator(creator);

    tripListView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            Trip trip = tripAdapter.getItem(position);
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    delete(trip);
                    tripAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

My biggest problem is that I just don't understand quite where I am adding the child to the parent where it would already have a parent.

All of my source code can be found [here](https://github.com/alyons/GasTrackingApp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_trips_overview, container, true);
```

use:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_trips_overview, container, false);
```

Notice the last parameter is `false` now. If you use `true`, the view you just created will be automatically added to the container (second parameter of inflate). With fragments, always use `false` in `onCreateView(...)`.